# How to find the power series for $g(z) = \frac{1}{(1 + 4z) ^ 3}$?

Tags: real-analysis, power-series

Here is my question. Find the power series, centered at -3 substitute $u = z+3$ and starting at $n = 0$ for the function given by $g(z) = \frac{1}{(1 + 4z) ^ 3}$.

So, this is what I know:
I must differentiate  or integrate it or substitute it. I need to use a known series like the following:
$$\sum_{n=0}^{\infty}x^n=\frac{1}{(1-x)}, x\in]-1,1[$$
or $$\sum_{n=0}^{\infty}(-1)^nx^2n=\frac{1}{(1-x^2)}, x\in]-1,1[$$
or $$\sum_{n=0}^{\infty}\frac{(-1)^nx^{2n+1}}{(2n+1)!}=\sin(x), x\in \mathbb{R}$$
or $$\sum_{n=0}^{\infty}\frac{(-1)^nx^{2n+1}}{(2n+1)}=\arctan(x), x\in [-1,1]$$
or $$\sum_{n=0}^{\infty}\frac{(-1)^nx^{2n}}{(2n)!}=\cos(x), x\in \mathbb{R}$$

I am not sure how to solve it. Suggestions will be welcome.  Thank you.

Comment: Take the first one, and do multiple derivatives of it.

Comment: @RobertTheTutor Note that he needs the sum to be centered at $-3,$ not $0.$ So there's a little more trickery needed.

Comment: Yes, you thought to add $ (z + 3) ^ n $

Comment: instead of editing to completely change your question, please start a new one

Answer (score 1):

If our power series is going to be centered at $-3,$ then we're going to want powers of $z + 3$ in our series. So, it makes sense to begin by rewriting our function in terms of $z + 3,$ which we can do like this:

$$g(z) = \frac{1}{(1 + 4z)^3} = \frac{1}{(1 + 4(z + 3 - 3))^3} = \frac{1}{(-11 + 4(z+3))^3}$$

It would be nice for us to have that first term in the denominator be a $1$ instead of an $11,$ so divide by $-11^3$ in the numerator and denominator to get

$$g(z) = -\frac{1}{11^3}\frac{1}{(1 - \frac{4}{11}(z+3))^3}$$

Now let $u = \frac4{11}(z + 3)$ and we have $$g(z) = -\frac1{11^3} \frac{1}{(1-u)^3}$$

Consider the derivatives of $f(z) = \frac{1}{1-z}.$ Taking our first derivative should give $\frac{1}{(1-z)^2}$ and taking another gives $\frac{2}{(1-z)^3}.$ Note the similarity between $f''$ and $g$.

We can get a power series for $f''$ by differentiating the power series for $f,$ which you've given as $\sum_{k=0}^{\infty} z^k.$ Differentiating termwise gives us $f' = \sum_{k=1}^{\infty} kz^{k-1}$ and $f'' = \sum_{k=2}^{\infty} k(k-1)z^{k-2}.$ If you'd like, you can reindex this as $f'' = \sum_{k=0}^{\infty} (k+2)(k+1)z^k$ so that $k$ always starts at zero.

So, $f''(z) = \frac{2}{(1-z)^3} = \sum_{k=0}^{\infty} (k+1)(k+2)z^k,$ which implies that $\frac{1}{(1-z)^3} = \frac12 \sum_{k=0}^{\infty} (k+1)(k+2)z^k$ after dividing both sides by $2.$

Finally, we can write that $$g(z) = -\frac{1}{11^3}\frac{1}{(1 - u)^3} = -\frac{1}{11^3} \frac{1}{2}\sum_{k=0}^{\infty} (k+1)(k+2)u^k$$
$$ = -\frac{1}{2 \cdot 11^3}\sum_{k=0}^{\infty} (k+1)(k+2)\left(\frac{4}{11}(z+3)\right)^k$$

Hope this helps!

Answer (score 0):

Starting with
$$
\frac{1}{1-x} = \sum_{n=0}^{\infty} x^n
$$
and taking derivatives we get
$$
\frac{1}{(1-x)^2} = \sum_{n=0}^{\infty} n x^{n-1}
\\
\frac{2}{(1-x)^3} = \sum_{n=0}^{\infty} n(n-1) x^{n-2}
$$

Setting $x=-4z$ then gives
$$
\frac{2}{(1+4z)^3} 
= \sum_{n=0}^{\infty} n(n-1) (-4z)^{n-2}
= \sum_{n=2}^{\infty} n(n-1) (-4z)^{n-2}
= \sum_{n=0}^{\infty} (n+2)(n+1) (-4z)^{n}.
$$